# How can i make two list items go on the other side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am recreating Google's page as practice, I have looked and looked, but how can I make two li, gmail and images, appear on the right side of the page? Also what can I improve on in my code?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.searchbar {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar {
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Store</li>
    <li>Gmail</li>
    <li>Images</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="google">
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19644.png" alt="google">
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from asking open ended questions like "how can I improve my code" - that will get the question down voted as it often elicits opinions. The first half is a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal way is to have separate menu `ul` for the left and for right side of the screen.

So then you can use `float` property to move the menu for right to the right side in a clean way.

The code will look like this:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.searchbar {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar {
  word-spacing: 10px;
}

.menu_left{
  float: left;
}

.menu_right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_bar">
  <ul class="menu_left">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Store</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu_right">
    <li>Gmail</li>
    <li>Images</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="google">
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19644.png" alt="google">
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search">
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot, I did not even think of making two menu's. It looks so much better now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to float the element to the right, for instance with:

```
.nav_bar ul {
  float: right;
}
```

As a more general comment, you could organize the HTML and CSS in different files, to better diferentiate between the content and the styles. Try to follow the [W3 basic tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) to catch the first concepts behind markup for the web.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to say. The only thing I would add is that sometimes you may need to clear the float after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have understand that you want to put only "images" and "gmail" on the right, so you can do this (the code is on the comment)

Good luck

```
<nav class="nav_bar">
      <ul>
    <li>About</li>
        <li>Store</li>
        <li>Images</li>
        <li>Gmail</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
        <div class="google">
          <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19644.png" alt="google">
        </div>
    <div class="searchbar">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  font-family: Arial;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline;
  float:left;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15%;
}
.searchbar {
  text-align:center;
}
.nav_bar {
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
nav.nav_bar li:nth-child(3), nav.nav_bar li:nth-child(4) {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Include the actual code in your answer, not just a jsfiddle link.